# Extracting first letter from specific vector in dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset, extract, letter

I am working in R with a babyname dataset.
The data set contains a column called name: `babies1900$name`. 
I know how to extract the last letter from each row in vector name.

```
last.letter.1900 <- substr(babies1900$name, nchar(babies1900$name), 
                                            nchar(babies1900$name))
```

I was interested in doing the same for the first letter for a dataset from a different year.
This is what I did, but am wondering if there a more "elegant" way of doing it.

```
x = babies2009$name

x = nchar(x)

y= x + 1

z = y -x

z =
[1] 1

babies.test = substr(babies2009$name, z, z)
```

This totally works, but is there a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might not get the question, but:

```
substr(babies2009$name, 1, 1)
```